# Windows Deployment Server-RAID Controller

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2012, deployment, pxe, imaging

I am to attempting to install Windows 7 onto Dell Workstations using WinPE drivers injected into a Deployment Workbench.

Despite injecting the RAID card drives (Perc 310 to be specific) I cannot get the RAID 1 Terabyte disk to come up.

I am using Windows Server 2012 to compile the preboot and drive stores.

Comment: Double check your drivers?

Comment: does anything come up with the diskpart / list disk command in WinPE?